# How to safely display an electric car's battery pack at a car show?

Tags: car, safety

My SO built a custom electric car which has a large high voltage battery pack in the trunk. We occasionally take it to fun local car shows. The battery pack generates a lot of interest so we like to display it. I always get a little nervous because these are family events with lots of little kids so I end up hovering making sure none of the kids try to touch. (The batteries look like bright blue legos and are eye level for 5-6 year olds). We put up no touching signs but I'm looking for better ideas to "people-proof" it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Display your battery pack through a window.

A sheet of rigid plexiglass will be transparent enough to see everything but stop anything from touching the dangerous parts of the display.

In addition, you can attach notes, arrows, and other marks to make the display more informative.
(I'm a science teacher.)

Comment: I love the idea of adding notes and arrows to make it kid-friendly as well as kid-safe! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put up a folding fire guard or screen around the backside of the car - something like this (but with no/less flame)

If parked on lawn/grass you could use a couple of tent pegs to stake the fence into the soil.  If parked on tarmac/sealed/hard surface, then a couple of sandbags should stop it being pushed around.

[image: https://www.turfrey.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Metro-Ambie-Plus-CGuard-A4-Situ-e1485033907894.jpg]

One advantage is these are see-through, and won't catch any wind gusts.